# How to "refresh" (in c#) a word document with table of contents in order to get correct page for a Field?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

My requirement is to retrieve the page number and location of a Range from a Word document using ms office interop (c#). In particular, I am looking for a field's page, while looping through the document's fields.

I discovered that my problem is with documents that have (at beginning) "generated" things like table of contents, table of lists, table of figures.

So, for me, fields that are on the second page are reported to be on the first. If I delete the TOC and replace with spaces, the same Range is reported on the correct page.

This is the relevant part of the code ...

```
foreach (Field field in wordDocument.Fields)
{
    field.Code.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) 
}
```

... and, again, works fine if there is no TOC or other generated elements.

Also, what works apparently is I try to find the page for a Range representing some text.

```
        if (range.Find.Execute(FindText: "xyz", MatchCase: false, Format: false, MatchWildcards: true, Forward: true))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("xyz page number is " + range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber));
        }
```

But I would really like to take advantage of the available list of fields, rather than searching through the document for text.
I tried a few things like looping through the tables and updating them, re-paginating, making the application visible. Nothing seems to work in my attempts to basically refresh the document, and make the TOC take its "space" so that the page number is reported correctly.

Anyone knows what I am missing?

thanks,
Cris

p.s. I doubt that it matters but basically I am trying to build "list of figures (or tables)", when there isn't one, for bookmarking purposes. So, I am looking for certain Fields that are Captions and I need page and position.

Comment: Word is quite buggy when retrieving the page number of a range... How about not getting the the page number from `field.Code` but from the range just before/behind the field?

Comment: @DirkVollmar I need to get create a bookmark (in PDF) for the field, so I need to page number and position for the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment it seems the solution to get a reliable page number for this type of field is to loop through the document paragraphs, instead of the document fields (i.e. even though I get to the same fields).

Anyway, I ended up with something like:

```
foreach (Paragraph parag in wordDocument.Paragraphs)
{
    foreach (Field field in parag.Range.Fields)
    {
        // e.g. SEQ Equation \* ARABIC § MyEquation
        if (field.Code.Text.StartsWith("SEQ "))
        {
              pageNo = parag.Range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber);
              ...
        }
    }
}
```